# Load only the submenus under given menu

Tags: 7

How to get ONLY the list of Submenus under given menu programmatically. Say, the `given menu` means a `main-menu` item. I tried with `menu_tree_page_data`. But not sure if I can use it to select only the required menus.

The scenario is, I have active menu loaded using `menu_get_active_trail()`. So I have all the details of the main menu. Now with those details I need to get the submenus under that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$main_menu_tree = menu_tree('main-menu');
foreach ($main_menu_tree as $key => &$main_menu_item) {
    if (is_numeric($key)) {
        $main_menu_item['#below']['#theme_wrappers'][0] = 'some_other_theme_wrapper';
    }
}
print drupal_render($main_menu_tree);
```

If you have array of main menu active trails you can use foreach to loop through the array print menus and their sub menus.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and it should work. I tested it now and it works by fetching sub menus.

```
$menuItems = menu_tree_page_data('main-menu');
foreach($menuItems as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $menuKey => $submenus) {
        if(isset($submenus['link_title'])) {
            print $submenus['link_title'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will get all the Sub-menus not sub-menus only under a given menu.

Answer (score 0):

if you just a specified Menuitem subItems just put a if between 2 foreach

```
$menuItems = menu_tree_page_data('main-menu');
$sub=array();
foreach($menuItems as $key => $value) {
if($menuKey=='yourmenuitemkey'){
    foreach($value as $menuKey => $submenus) {
        if(isset($submenus['link_title'])) {
            $sub[]=$submenus['link_title'];
        }
      }
    } 
  }
```